# How to put tooltip bullet inline with the label field

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to put the button inline with the label and bellow them to have the full width input.
What I've made is this:

```
<div class="container">
   <label>Tralala</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Tralalala">
   <button type="tooltip" data="This is tralalala">This is tralalala</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <label>Tralala Tralalala Tralalala</label>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Tralala Tralalala Tralalala">
   <button type="tooltip" data="This is Tralala Tralalala Tralalala">This is Tralala Tralalala Tralalala</button>
</div>
```

So there is no posibility for me to put the button inside the label and I have to use CSS to make it.
My CSS looks like this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container label { order: 0 }
.container input { order: 2 }
.container button {oder: 1 }
```

But from here, I don't know how to bring the label and button inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

Change the flex-direction to `row` and allow wrapping.

Change the `order` so the `input`comes after the other elements and then make it 100% wide.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 1em;
}

button {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

input {
  order: 2;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Tralala</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Tralalala">
  <button type="tooltip" data="This is tralalala">This is tralalala</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <label>Tralala Tralalala Tralalala</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Tralala Tralalala Tralalala">
  <button type="tooltip" data="This is Tralala Tralalala Tralalala">This is Tralala Tralalala Tralalala</button>
</div>
```